# Haxe - Text doesn't show on desktop app but shows in HTML5 version

Tags: windows, flash, text, global-variables, haxeflixel

I am using [HaxeFlixel](https://haxeflixel.com/).
The code below shows what I'm doing for the text, this happens with every state of the game. I'm in a Game Jam so I need something to solve this...

```
#if flash

money.text = 'Legacy Coins\n$globalCoin'; // for the html5

#else

money.text = 'Legacy Coins\n' + globalCoin; //for the desktop

#end
```

The image below is showing the error. 
*note: one of of the screens is paused but the same happens even without the pause.*

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this code is related to the captures ? "Legacy coins" is in a different font and there is a colon. Also, the newline in the text might hide some of the text if it doesn't fit in the textarea ?

Comment: this is a text from other state but does the same as the image in the html5 it works fine but in the windows it don't shows the numbers, the width is from the FlxG class so if the text is big the FlxG will fix the width... the legacy coins is the text that display on the screen the font is SPACEBAR.ttf... the second code is for trying to extract the variable from other way.

Comment: Both lines of code do the same, have try without if statement? I expect font issue. Is your font on desktop contains numbers? Have you try with a bigger textfield on desktop?